# Show the list of the files inside the folder of the current file

Tags: vim

Imagine I'm editing file, and I want to show the list of the files inside the folder who belongs the file I'm editing, to edit one of them.

How can I do that? Is there any way using `FuzzyFinder`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you even read FuzzyFinder's documentation (`:help fuzzyfinder`)? Quickly opening nearby files is one of that plugin's main features.

- Without installing anything, you can do:

  ```
  :Ex[plore]
  ```

  to open the `netrw` file tree. See `:help netrw`.
- You can also do:

  ```
  :e <Tab>
  ```

  Add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` to make command line completion even better:

  ```
  set wildmenu
  set wildmode=list:full
  ```

  and read `:help wildmenu` and `:help commandline-completion`.

`set autochdir` is a useful option to add to your `~/.vimrc`, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

change vim current directory to current file's:

```
:cd %:h
```

then

FuzzyFinder can do what you want (pick and edit). (`:FufFile`) I have mapping :

```
nmap <Leader>ff :FufFile<cr>
```

NERDTree can do that as well.

Comment: I like that way, but I would have to change later to the root project folder again..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by showing the file.

To include the list of files in the currently edited files, you can do something like:

```
:read !ls /path/to/file
```

(it can be shortened to `:cd %:h | read !ls` if you don't mind if `vim` changes it's current directory...)

If you want to pick another file to edit, I'd suggest to take a look at [NerdTree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) plugin ([here is](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/vim-plugins-nerdtree-vim/) a little intro). Or you can simply issue:

```
:cd %:h | e .
```

Comment: I think :cd will switch to $HOME not current. so :cd|e . will open $HOME directory right?